# Why does returning background back to transparent via JavaScript fail in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, background-color, transparent

I have a navigation menu and logo on top of my page. Initially the background color is transparent. On scroll, it changes to 60% opaque black. If the user scrolls back to the top, the menu's background should return to 100% transparency.

I tested it in Chrome, IE, Opera (works) and Firefox (does not work). I tried
`style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';` and `.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';`

JS:

```
function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
    document.getElementById("main_menu").style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)';
    document.querySelector(".callout").style.fontSize = "2.4rem";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("main_menu").style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';
    document.querySelector(".callout").style.fontSize = "3rem";
  }
}
```

And the related HTML:

```
        <header id="page_header">
          <a href="index.html" class="callout">Placeholder Logo Text</a>
        </header>
        <!-- main navigation -->
        <nav id="main-nav">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
```

My guess is that the problem is related to Firefox's default background color being white (right?). But if my function sets it to transparent, why is it not working?

Edit: It works in Firefox when I test the page on a local server. Other JavaScript functions I made worked just fine in Firefox when I tested them without having the server running. I'm only starting out with this, though. Could anyone tell me what makes this function different for Firefox?

Comment: What is `main_menu`?

Comment: `does not work` what happens? what do you expect instead? I see absolutely no difference between browsers with the code you've shown

Comment: Oh, sorry! 
What's not working in Firefox is that, when I scroll back up, the opacity doesn't change back to transparent. It stays 60% black.

`main_menu` is the div the HTML code I posted is wrapped in.

Comment: @Cinder Did you debug the code? What parts of it run in Firefox?

Comment: I found out that, when I test the page on a local server, everything runs as it should also in Firefox: the menu is initially transparent, gets a 60% black background on scrolling down and on scrolling up, the background returns to transparent. But when I test the page in a browser (without the local server running), it doesn't return its transparent state when scrolling up.